# Unable to get login application to work

Tags: java, jdbc

This method is always returning false for some reason. I have entered the correct credentials and tried but returning false the caller. Please help.

```
public Boolean validate(String username, String password) {

    System.out.println(username);
    System.out.println(password);

    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login?"+"user=Naveen&password=Naveen");

        String sql = "select * from login.user where username=? and password=?";

        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        pst.setString(0, username);
        pst.setString(1, password);

        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also please add system.out.println(e) in your catch block to get the actual error. As per your code whatever error you get it returns as false and does not point out the error

Comment: Yeah, I will do that, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Parameter indexes for `PreparedStatement` start with `1` not `0`. Proper way to set parameters would be:

```
PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, username);
pst.setString(2, password);
```

I also suggest using try-with-resources blocks for `Closeable` resources such as `Connection` or `PreparedStatement`. Or at least closing them in finally block if you are using Java prior 7.

Answer (score 0):

The root case is that you code always goes into catch block and returns `false`.

You should use right indexes for `PreparedStatement` clasure. **The fisrt one should be 1 instead of 0**.

Note: you should also process `Exceptions` in right way (at least print the error message in console, it will be helpfull)